# Angular JS ng-Switch to display hyperlink based on Values Inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html

I am trying to use ng-switch to display different hyperlink such as Modify/Approve/Reject But the hyper link is not showing up on screen , when i use it to display text it is working . what am i missing . This is my HTML

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat='item in errorsd'>
<td ng-switch={{val.action}} align="left" class="validationMsg">
<span ng-switch-when="View"><a href style="cursor: pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editWindow" ng-click="ModifyConfig(details)">Modify</a></span>
<span ng-switch-when=Approve><a href style="cursor: pointer" data-toggle="modal"data-target="#editWindow" ng-click="RejectConfig(details)">Reject</a></span>
  <!-- and so on.. -->
</td>
```

Comment: Is `val` defined somewhere?

Comment: yes , the value comes as View / approve . I'm able to see it in the DOM

Comment: `<td class="list" align="center" ng-switch="Approve">`
`<!-- ngSwitchWhen:View -->`
`<!-- ngSwitchWhen:Approve -->`
`</td>`

Answer (score 1):

`ng-switch-when` needs expression to compare, so wrap value with `'`(single quote) would do the trick. Addionally remove `{{}}`(interpolation directive) from `ng-switch` directive as it needs only expression.

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat='item in errorsd'>
    <td ng-switch="val.action" align="left" class="validationMsg">
        <span ng-switch-when="'View'">
          <a href style="cursor: pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editWindow" ng-click="ModifyConfig(details)">Modify</a>
        </span>
        <span ng-switch-when="'Approve'">
          <a href style="cursor: pointer" data-toggle="modal"data-target="#editWindow" ng-click="RejectConfig(details)">Reject</a>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I tried adding single quotes it didnt work ,if i remove {{}} i will not be able to get the value of val.action

Comment: @Praveen `ng-switch` needs scope variable to watch & whatever value of `val.action`, it will compare to `ng-switch-when` values, and show the appropriate based on `val.action` value evaluation..

Comment: plus 1 for tip on removing interpolation

Comment: It is also a scope variable , but  the value is not present inside errorsd  . So when i use ng-repeat to loop it over the item is not present here . so i used {{}} to accept the value

Comment: @Praveen what is `val`? where it is defined?

Comment: The val is not present inside the errorsd .  The val is present inside the same controller

Comment: @Praveen then it should work, provide plunker with reproducible problem.. I'll hellp you out

Answer (score 0):

first your ng-repeat creates the variable "item",
that should be used in your ng-switch ("val" is not known)

```
<td ng-switch="item.action">
```

then you missed the quotes here:

```
<span ng-switch-when=Approve>
```

Working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/pB1tldrskxbyIET9GvPU?p=preview)

Comment: I dont have the value in item.action , i have it inside val.action

Comment: then it should be item.val.action, or post the structure of errorsd